# HtmlAgilityPack loop thru. table in VB.NET

Tags: html-agility-pack

in the below example i'm able to download both documents (order and invoice) just fine. However, I can't determine which document is the order and which is the invoice.  How can I use the HtmlAgility to loop and find the "View INVOICE" then grab the next URL link so I can assign the doc. as an invoice.

example HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td><a href="http://www.weburl.com">    <img id="Image1"       src="http://www.weburl.com/App_Themes/Granite/Images/Logo.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" /></a></td><td> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src="http://www.weburl.com/images/ALT/Priority.gif" style="border-width:0px;" /></td></tr></table></div><br /><div align="center"><center><table border="0"><tr><td  width="100%"><div align="center"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td colspan="2" align="center" nowrap>Documents on file for order# <b>285006797</b><br />&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td align="right"><font color="#800000"><b>View ORDER:&nbsp; </font></b></td><td><A HREF="xrecord.asp?s=RK=SOFTWARE\Pegasus Transtech\WebDirect;US=WEBPRI;PW=WEBPRI&docinfo=13409811"target="_blank"> Page 1</A> 
<tr><td align="right"><font color="#800000"><b>View INVOICE:&nbsp; </font></b></td><td><A HREF="xrecord.asp?s=RK=SOFTWARE\Pegasus Transtech\WebDirect;US=WEBPRI;PW=WEBPRI&docinfo=13496712"target="_blank"> Page 1</A> 
<tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><br />Click the page number to view the documents.<br /><hr></td></tr>
</table></div></td></tr></table>
    </body>
</html>
```